# Combine three functions into one - GAS JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have these functions that you can see below. The functions all works (alone). The functions only work with the excact Google DOC ID that I entered directly in the script.

So I want to build the **getListOfId()** and **moveSheet1()** function into the **getDocItems()** and **runsies()** functions.

The variable -> **var docFilesId = [];** in the **getListOfId()** function contains the entire IDS from the folder that are in my Google Drive. They are all Google DOCS files.

That means: the function **runsies()** should be repeated and executed until all documents have been read out and all data has been gradually written into the cell.

I tried a loop, but unfortunately it didn't work. I don't know how I can integrate the IDS "var = docFilesID []" into the other functions.

I hope you have now understood my concern.

**Short Summary:**

1. Function is executed ->
2. Cell is checked whether it is empty ->
3. If the cell is not empty, it is moved ->
4. All Google DOC IDS from the folder are read and stored in the array ->
5. The first Google DOC ID from thies array above is used ->
6. Data from the Google DOC are read out and stored in an another array ->
7. Data in second array are entered in the cell->
8. -> -> -> ->
9. The sequence is carried out until all IDS have been run through ->
   -> ->

---

```
    function getDocItems(docID, identifier){
      const body = DocumentApp.openById("13TlciLOZV-rxj1aV4qFdeBoMuEocGNgCSb7_uXXoZDQ").getBody();
      const docText = body.getText();
      
      //Check if search characters are to be included. 
      let startLen =  identifier.start_include ? 0 : identifier.start.length;
      let endLen = identifier.end_include ? 0 : identifier.end.length;
      
      //Set up the reference loop
      let textStart = 0;
      let doc = docText;
      let docList = [];
      
      //Loop through text grab the identifier items. Start loop from last set of end identfiers.
      while(textStart > -1){ 
        let textStart = doc.indexOf(identifier.start);
        
        if(textStart === -1){
          break;  
        }else{
          
          let textEnd = doc.indexOf(identifier.end) + identifier.end.length;
          let word = doc.substring(textStart,textEnd);
          
          doc = doc.substring(textEnd);
          
          docList.push(word.substring(startLen,word.length - endLen));
        };
      };
      //return a unique set of identifiers. 
      return [...new Set(docList)];
    };
    
    
    //The "Main" function
    function runsies(){
      const docID = "13TlciLOZV-rxXXXXXXXXXXcGNgCSb7_uXXoZDQ";
      const identifier = {
        start: `ISIN: `,
        start_include: false,
        end: `VERRECHNUNGSKONTO`,
        end_include: false
      };
      let results = getDocItems(docID, identifier);
      //var commaAdd = results.join("''");
      //console.log(results);
      
      const ss = "17a55HCwlO5uF8gXXXXXXXXXXfltlV0UTcHh7vG7A";//The spreadsheet ID
      const sheet = "Stock_Data";//The sheet tab name
      var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      let importToSpredsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getSheetByName(sheet);
      const range = activeSheet.getRange(6,1,results.length,1);
      range.setValue(results);
      //range.sort([2,1]);
    };
____________
      var docFilesId = [];                           //array of files ids from folder
    
      function getListOfId(){
        var folderId = "11tjb_oXXXXXXXXXXY9DViQQJ8u9-g";
        var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
        while (filesN.hasNext()) docFilesId.push(filesN.next().getId());
    }
________
     function moveSheet1() {
          var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Selects the spreadsheet
          var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName("Stock_Data"); // Selects Sheet 1
          var data = ss1.getRange(6,1).getValues(); // Gets all values in the sheet
          var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName("Stock_Data2"); // Selects Sheet 2
          var cell = ss.getRange("A6").isBlank();
          if (!cell){
            ss1.getRange(6, 1, ss1.getLastRow() - STOCKDATA_ROW_OFFSET, ss1.getLastColumn()).moveTo(ss1.getRange(7, 1));
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the function `runsies()` on all documents, then you probably can move what you did with `getListOfId()` to inside the `runsies()` function.

Also, since it'll run for multiple files, you probably want to append the results instead of always writing them to the same range:

```
function runsies(){
  var folderId = "11tjb_oXXXXXXXXXXY9DViQQJ8u9-g";           //Added
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();  //Added
  while (filesN.hasNext()) {                                 //Changed
    const docID = filesN.next().getId();                     //Changed
    const identifier = {
      start: `ISIN: `,
      start_include: false,
      end: `VERRECHNUNGSKONTO`,
      end_include: false
    };
    let results = getDocItems(docID, identifier);
    //var commaAdd = results.join("''");
    //console.log(results);
    
    const ss = "17a55HCwlO5uF8gXXXXXXXXXXfltlV0UTcHh7vG7A";//The spreadsheet ID
    const sheet = "Stock_Data";//The sheet tab name
    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let importToSpredsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss).getSheetByName(sheet);
    importToSpredsheet.insertRowBefore(6);                   //Added
    const range = activeSheet.getRange(6,1,results.length,1);
    range.setValue(results);
    range.sort([2,1]);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your proposed solution is going in the right direction. But I want the data to be always written to the same cell. That's why I added the moveSheet1 () function. If the cell is filled with the data in the first run, it should be moved down one cell in the second run. The data from the second pass should then be written back into the prescribed cell. At the end of the run, all data are in different cells, one below the other. 1 cell = 1 document.

Comment: So instead of writing new data to the end, you want to write new data to a fixed position and push old data to a row down?

Comment: I agree. The cell in which the data is written from a file remains the same. The second time the function is run, the previously filled cell is simply moved downwards.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's very efficient, because you'd shift all the rows every time a new file is found. But, in any case, I changed the code to insert a new row at index 6, so then you can use your original code to write to it. Alternatively, you can also read all the rows with a getDataRange().getValues(), then add the new row to the array and write everything back using setValues().

Comment: Thank you. The script now reads the files and adds as many empty cells as there are files in the folder. Unfortunately, the script only reads the first file and then it stops running.
That is actually my main problem too.
The script always reads only one file and then writes it into the cell, but then stops, so that at the end only the information from one file is in the spreadsheet.